# Rails uniform DateTime timezone for european format CEST/CET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently seeing an issue since the system time has changed from CEST(+02:00) to CET (+01:00) on my Rails application.

The issue I get is that for some reason some DateTime get saved as CET and others as CEST creating a record right now. The issue is that when retrieving that data from the database and using a strftime("%H:%M") it prints out a wrong value, so if for example it was saved as CEST it prints out "10:00", while it prints "09:00" if saved as CET.

How can I force the system to always use +0200 or +0100?

By running `Time.zone` I get "(GMT+01:00) ROME" while running `Time.zone.now` I get the timestamp +0200.

How can I fix this inconsistence? My `config.time_zone` is set to "Rome".

P.S. I'm using Rails 3.2.13

Comment: store everything as UTC, then convert to whatever timezone is necessary at displaytime.

Comment: Actually if I try to update my DateTime field it keeps the same timezone, also if I force it by calling `DateTime.utc` :-/

Comment: I mean that by doing `date.utc.in_local_time` on a CEST date, it gets back as CEST, while doing the same on a CET date returns the CET representation. Shouldn't get the timezone get lost by running `utc`?

Comment: @MarcB see this is what I'm doing: `e.start_at = DateTime.parse("28/10/2013 19:00 +0200")` but when I then retrieve it it's still "CET". Time.now and DateTime.now is CEST. How's this possible? `e.created_at` is CEST.

Answer (score 3):

Problem found.

The issue raises when I'm working with dates >= 26/10/2013 that ruby correctly returns with the time_zone associated to the DateTime time stamp (not the current one). So all dates after the CET adoption are treated as CET automatically.

Working with UTC at the database level seems the right way to do that.